# e.Handled in RichTextBox has no effect. On TextBox, it works

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The following code eats the Enter key for a TextBox (with "MultiLine" set to True):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress


    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then

        e.Handled = True

    End If

End Sub
```

The same code for a RichTextBox however doesn't work: The Enter key is not eaten:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyPress

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then

        e.Handled = True

    End If

End Sub
```

I don't see where I could have made a mistake.

Does anybody see where this behaviour might come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.
I needs to be consumed in KeyDown. Unlike for TextBox:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```